# Unify the behaviour of the back button after calling window.location.replace(...) with a hash fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, back-button, browser-history

I'm getting different behaviour of the back button after calling `window.location.replace(...)`, but I need to find a way to get the same behaviour across all browsers (mobile included).

Given the following html (contained within a file testpage.html):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="window.location.replace('testpage.html#test2');">Replace</button>
        <button onclick="window.location.assign('testpage.html#test3');">Assign</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Initially the url is testpage.html.

1. Click the replace button - URL changes to testpage.html#test2
2. Click the assign button - URL changes to testpge.html#test3
3. Click the back button...

Then different browsers do different things:

- On Chrome (21) and Firefox (15) the URL changes back to testpage.html#test2 and no further back click is possible. **This is what I would expect, and this is the exact behaviour I want.**
- On Safari (5) and iOS (5) the URL changes back to testpage.html (with no hash fragment) entirely skipping over the intermediate URL containing #test2.
- On IE (9) and WP7 the url jumps completely back to whatever I was on before testpage.html
- On the android browser (gingerbread and ice cream sandwich) the first click on the replace button doesn't do anything (incorrect behaviour). The second click on the assign button sets the url to testpage.html#test3 as expected. The back button then returns the url to testpage.html with no hash fragment, which is the same as Safari and iOS, but in the context of the fact that the first button click didn't do anything, this seems like the correct behaviour. The issue is that the call to `replace(...)` doesn't work.

Is there anyway reason why the behaviour is different? Is there any way to unify the behaviour of to match what I'm getting on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Interesting question and observation. History.js to the rescue perhaps?